# Excel - automatic input to next empty row

Tags: java, excel, file-io, archive

I'm developing a program that stores specific data in an excel archive. I wrote a code that creates an excel file, sheet and writes in it. My code is shown below. The problem is that when writing in the archive I have to specify the row that it should insert the information into. Is there anyway to make the code automatically insert in the next new empty row by itself?

```
package de.vogella.java.excel.writer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.write.Formula;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
public class WriteExcel {
private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
private WritableCellFormat times;
private String inputFile;

public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
this.inputFile = inputFile;
}

public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
File file = new File(inputFile);
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
createLabel(excelSheet);
createContent(excelSheet);
workbook.write();
workbook.close(); }
private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet)
  throws WriteException {
// Lets create a times font
WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
// Define the cell format
times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
// Lets automatically wrap the cells
times.setWrap(true);

 // create create a bold font with unterlines
 WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
 UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
 timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
 // Lets automatically wrap the cells
 timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

 CellView cv = new CellView();
 cv.setFormat(times);
 cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
 cv.setAutosize(true);
 // Write a few headers
 addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "type");
 addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "result");
 addCaption(sheet, 2, 0, "time");
 addCaption(sheet, 3, 0, "date");}
 private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException,
 RowsExceededException {
 // Write a few number
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
 // First column
 addLabel(sheet, 0, i, "Boring text " + i);
 // Second column
 addNumber(sheet, 1, i, i * i);
 // third column
 addNumber(sheet, 2, i, i + 10);
 //furth column
 addNumber(sheet, 3, i, i * i);} }
 private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
 throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
 Label label;
 label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
 sheet.addCell(label); }
 private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
 Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
 Number number;
 number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
 sheet.addCell(number); } 
 private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
 throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
 Label label;
 label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
 sheet.addCell(label);}
 public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, IOException {
 WriteExcel test = new WriteExcel();
 test.setOutputFile("D:ghada.xls");
 test.write();
 System.out.println("Please check the result file under c:/temp/lars.xls "); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used that API, so do not know if there is a better way to do this. Also, Java isn't my thing so cant give you any code examples.

You need to find the first empty row in your spreadsheet. Assuming Column A is always populated, you can just loop from row 1 to N until you find an empty row.

The tutorial for the API you're using shows how you can read an excel file.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html